# parseFloat is doubling operand in animation

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I'm very new to JavaScript and to coding in general. I'm creating an animation that expands and contract an image to simulate breathing. I am also adding a "breath count" to count the number of breaths. This is the code I used to create the breath count:

```
 <h1> Breath Number: <span id= "countingBreaths">0</span> </h1>
```

Then in the script tag:

```
//function for breath number increase
    var countingTo = function() {
      countingBreaths.textContent = 1 + (parseFloat(countingBreaths.textContent));

      var startCounting = setInterval(countingTo, 4000);

      var stopCounting = function () {
        clearInterval(startCounting);
      }
      stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopCounting);
    }

    startButton.addEventListener("click", countingTo);
```

My problem is in the parseFloat function. My intention is to increase the breath number by 1 (+1). But, instead, it is doubling my number (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc). I'm not sure what I did wrong. I've tried everything and looked on this site for help but can't find any information. I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: Every time `countingTo()` is invoked, it starts another interval timer. First there'll be one timer, then two, then four, then eight, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pointy wrote in the comment [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) will create a timer that calls it's function every 4 seconds.

And you start a new timer every time time the function runs, so eventually you have a lot of timers. And each one will increase your breathCount.

Maybe you confused [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). Then every function call would only prepare the next one:

```
var countingTo = function() {
  countingBreaths.textContent = 1 + (parseFloat(countingBreaths.textContent));

  var startCounting = setTimeout(countingTo, 4000);

…
```

But you still would add a new click eventListener to your stop button on every function call. That means your stop function would be called a lot of times.
In your example it runs for each created interval.

So you should move that out of your `countingTo` function like this:

```
var intervalId = null
var countingTo = function() {
  countingBreaths.textContent = 1 + (parseFloat(countingBreaths.textContent));
}

var startCounting = function () {
  intervalId = setInterval(countingTo, 4000);
}

var stopCounting = function () {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}

startButton.addEventListener("click", startCounting);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopCounting);
```

Or with setTimeout:

```
var timeoutId = null
var countingTo = function() {
  countingBreaths.textContent = 1 + (parseFloat(countingBreaths.textContent));

  timeoutId = setTimeout(countingTo, 4000);
}

var stopCounting = function () {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}

startButton.addEventListener("click", countingTo);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopCounting);
```

Also if you are doing animations you might want to look into [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)